# Why moment.utc(...).diff(moment.utc(...)) gets affected by source date offsets

Tags: javascript, html, date, momentjs

Check the following code sample:

```
moment.utc("2014-10-19T09:27:57.9417128+00:00")
      .diff(moment.utc("2014-10-19T09:27:57.9417128+02:00"))
```

I would expect `0` since I'm converting both dates to UTC, but this gives `7200000` as result.

In fact, I'm looking to get `moment.fromNow` or `moment.from` to work with UTC in order to get a `X seconds/minutes/hours... ago` without an invalid result because of `Date`/`moment` translating date-times based on the date's offset.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would think the source offsets should be ignored. They are especially relevant for converting to UTC, because they actually represent the difference between UTC and the time represented.

In the first timestamp, the `+00:00` means the time is already at UTC.  In the second timestamp, the `+02:00` means the time is two hours *ahead* of UTC.  `2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 7200000`.

In other words:

```
    2014-10-19T09:27:57.9417128+00:00  ==  2014-10-19T09:27:57.9417128Z
-   2014-10-19T09:27:57.9417128+02:00  ==  2014-10-19T07:27:57.9417128Z
=======================================================================
                                                      02:00:00
```

There is no way the result should be zero, because any way you look at it, the two timestamps represent two different moments in time that are separated by two hours.

Since moment's `fromNow` function already works with the current UTC time, and you have a full ISO timestamp with an offset, you can just use it directly without any conversion.

```
moment("2014-10-19T09:27:57.9417128+02:00").fromNow()
```

You don't even need to convert to UTC first.  You *could* do it like this:

```
moment.utc("2014-10-19T09:27:57.9417128+02:00").fromNow()
```

But these will both return the same thing because you have already supplied the offset.  They would only differ if you *didn't* include an offset, in which case the first example would interpret the input string in local time and the second case would interpret the input string in UTC.  Neither of which change the behavior of the `fromNow` function.

Comment: I've removed my answer for now, but I believe we're confusing things. What I'm trying to achieve is getting how many time has passed since something happened regardless of the offset. I mean: if something happened now and someone wants to know how many time has passed since the first happened, it'll be always the same for anyone in the world, even if the user is in +08:00 offset and the server is +02:00

Comment: Sorry, but that's not true. I'm not sure why you would think that.  The offset is a reflection of the timestamp.  For example, on my clock right now, it's 12:17PM and my offset is -07:00.  For someone in +02:00, it is right now 9:17PM.  For both of us, it's 7:17PM UTC.

Comment: For me, when I do the `from` call, with my and your date, I would get that "something happened 7 hours ago" and this isn't true

Comment: Without the offset, you might get that.  But the offset ensures that wont happen as long as it was recorded correctly to begin with.  If for some strange reason you are disassociating the offset with the timestamp when you recorded it, that might explain the behavior you described, but under normal circumstances, that shouldn't happen.

Comment: So, do you still think my answer was wrong? If I want to know how much time has passed since some event happened in the world, I need both date-times in UTC (+00:00).

Comment: Your other answer was wrong because it used the local computer's offset, not the timestamp's offset.  You are correct that to compare, both values need to be in UTC.  `fromNow` uses the current UTC time (regardless of the local computer's time zone), and the time stamp sting you provided has an offset.  So that offset is used to adjust the time stamp back to UTC, then the two values are compared.  Make sense?

Comment: Earlier when you said "something happened 7 hours ago" wasn't true *for you*, you were likely not considering the offset in the "something", but rather your own offset.  If you were to adjust properly to your own time zone, you would find that it was indeed 7 hours ago.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're understanding the issue (maybe I'm missing something). Imagine it's a chat and someone posts a message and the other receives the whole message. The message is in the chat history and both users are in different time zones. This won't mean there're many hours of difference, because the event happened some seconds ago.

Comment: The offset needs to be in the time stamp in the chat history. Then it all works out. It wont show they are hours apart unless you ignore those offsets.

Comment: As I pointed out in my question, it's not working as expected. Try it yourself

Comment: Here.  Check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z01vuk9x/) showing a chat log between two parties in different time zones.  Each message is one minute apart.

Comment: You're right. Do you know what was the issue? I was still using moment 2.6.0. It seems like 2.6 had the issue, because I switched to 2.8.0 and it works like you showed me in the jsFiddle. In fact, my first tries was just doing like you, but since I wasn't getting the expected result............

Comment: Glad to help!  I'm not sure which bug it was that was fixed, but if you figure it out, let me know.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm nearly to be sure that my first attemp was doing just like your fiddle,  and I was getting unexpected results. Then, I thought: what if I turn dates into UTC+00:00? And it worked. Maybe I'm mistaken, but this has been the sequence :D

Comment: Hey... I've published another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483750/moment-fromnow-moment-from-returning-unexpected-ago-text-when-working-with-utc which is related to this... Either I'm understanding this at all or there's some issue here grr